# How to reduce too many parameters from constructor

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-core, sonarqube, coding-style

I used 9 parameters in the constructor in a command service class, but sonarqube shows an error for too many parameters.  Can anyone suggest a solution or design pattern solve this issue?

```
public CustomerCommandService(A a, B b, C c, D d, E e, F f, G g, H h, I i){
//some code here
}
```

Comment: This is not an error but rather a signal or a code smell telling you are giving too much responsibility on this class. Maybe you should apply single responsibility principle and break this class.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/311297/241751

Comment: In real developer work constructor that takes that amount of parameters is nothing special to be honest. Sometimes its hard to write methods without big amout of parameters to it.

Comment: Question is too broad as it stands now. There is no way to answer this question as it stands now in a concrete way as required on SO. You may try to convert the question into practical refactoring request (with code that has meaningful names and aligns with your actual code) or turn to search on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ as this type of problems likely discussed there (as @Div suggested)

Comment: @Emad we were in pre-coded large code base. so single responsibility method application need extra effort in this stage. but the right solution is that solution. do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @KelumSampathEdirisinghe, have you tried encapsulating the params in a struct and passing the struct to the CTOR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a Struct to contain your different Params and then passing this structure to your constructor

```
public struct CustomerParams
{
    A a;
    B b;
    ...
}
public CustomerCommandService(CustomerParams cp)
{

}
```

Comment: how can i access those struct params inside constructor?

Comment: didn't quiet understand, what do you mean how you access ?

Comment: i need to assign this 'a' and 'b' ... to local private variables inside constructor. how can i do it?

Comment: You can initialize the struct when you instantiate the constructor class, I do not have access to a VS now, if you can provide a more elaborate code snipped may be I can look at it

Comment: thanks, i sorted out that access problem. but service injection is not possible through struct it seems.

Comment: do you mean Dependency Injection ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204467/discussion-between-kelum-sampath-edirisinghe-and-clint).

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error but a warning. Anyway, you should avoid using as many parameters. Try to break your service into some sub-services. Also, as Div said, you could use the [builder pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311297/constructor-with-tons-of-parameters-vs-builder-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Struct, Class Object, or Tuple to achieve what you want.

Struct and Class are nearly the same,only the keyword will change. Sample:

```
struct Pack
{
     int a,b;
     float c,d;
     String e;
}

public static Main()
{
     Pack pack = new Pack();
     pack.a=10;
     pack.b=30;
     ...
     CustomerCommandService ccs = new CustomerCommandService(pack);
}

public CustomerCommandService(Pack pack){
      //some code here
}
```

Tuple sample:

```
public static Main()
{
     var pack = Tuple.Create(1, 2, 10.4, 30.5, "Steve");
     CustomerCommandService ccs = new CustomerCommandService(pack);
}

public CustomerCommandService(Tuple<int,int,float,float,string> pack){
      //some code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When a function seems to need more than two or three arguments, it is likely that some of
**those arguments ought to be wrapped into a class of their own**. Consider, for example, the
difference between the two following declarations:

```
Circle makeCircle(double x, double y, double radius);
Circle makeCircle(Point center, double radius);
```

Hopefully, [this](https://www.matheus.ro/2018/01/29/clean-code-avoid-many-arguments-functions/) post is helpful for you.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Also I have pointed this out in the comments. The question asks on how to reduce not that should he or should he not.

Comment: It kinda does. One method for reducing the code smell of passing multiple parameters, is to make them all properties of a parameter class.

Comment: Nope. In my opinion you just added a completely different and irrelevant thing.